# pg_stat_statements same query different queryid

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-statements

I am setting up a monitoring system for a PostgreSQL database and I am checking `pg_stat_statements`, however I have noticed this:

`SELECT queryid, query FROM pg_stat_statements WHERE query LIKE '%UPDATE pgbench_tellers%';`

results in:

```
8899387537716482989,UPDATE pgbench_tellers SET tbalance = tbalance + $1 WHERE tid = $2
5800668169761729302,UPDATE pgbench_tellers SET tbalance = tbalance + $1 WHERE tid = $2
-3652521024179043160,UPDATE pgbench_tellers SET tbalance = tbalance + $1 WHERE tid = $2
-8908321420070439827,UPDATE pgbench_tellers SET tbalance = tbalance + $1 WHERE tid = $2
```

Why is that so? Shouldn't be the same?

#### NOTE:

I am running pg_bench at 1 hour intervals, I suspect this has something to do with it as those new ids seems to be recorded exactly every hour.

Comment: "Stops the restart"?

Comment: it runs for 1 hour, then it finishes, print the report, exit with code 0 and the container is restarted automatically.

Comment: What happens to the database when the container restarts?  Is is cleanly stopped and then started again, or immediately stopped (unclean) and restarted, or thrown away and recreated?

Comment: The database never stops, pg_bench lives on it's own container

Comment: are dbid or userid different for each one?